# addEventListener for a Function in a Different Class

Tags: actionscript-3, class-design, addeventlistener

Quick ActionScript question, since I'm still getting used to the language:

Is it possible to pass addEventListener a function that is in a different class?  I.E.  I have Model call addEventListener(Event.NAME, Controller.function) or something along those lines.

*Probably* not a big deal if I can't do this, but I was just wondering for the sake of code organization etc.

Comment: I imagine you could, but not sure if you should. It might be safer on the long run to what the Models deals with internally as private functions inside your model, and dispatch custom events from your model to your controller only you need that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can as you can see in the following example I made:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            addChild(new CustomSprite);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class Global
{
    public static function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("onAddedToStage() called.");

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class CustomSprite extends Sprite
{
    public function CustomSprite()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Global.onAddedToStage);

    }// end function

}// end function
```

Personally I wouldn't suggest it though, although it could have some interesting applications.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for demonstrating that - In doing other research whilst waiting for an answer I don't think that's the route I'm going to end up going, but I appreciate your response!

Comment: No problem. You've actually got me thinking about ways this can be used.

Comment: Well feel free to keep me informed :-P  I'm still a pretty novice ActionScript developer, so miscellaneous applications are always interesting.